# Unable to send notifications using SNS MessageAttributes in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, sms, amazon-sns

I'm using SNS to send notifications to specific subscriptions in a topic based on message attributes. I'm able to send notifications to subscriptions from AWS console based on below message attributes,

[image: aws console]

but, when I try the same from golang I'm getting messageId and a successful response but the notification is not being sent. below is my golang code,

```
// foo.Addresses = ["foo@foo.com", "bar@bar.com"]
messageAttributes := make(map[string]*sns.MessageAttributeValue)
addresses, _ := json.Marshal(foo.Addresses)
messageAttributes["Custom"] = &sns.MessageAttributeValue{
    DataType:    aws.String("String.Array"),
    StringValue: aws.String(string(addresses)),
}

input := &sns.PublishInput{
    Subject:           &foo.Subject,
    Message:           &foo.Message,
    TopicArn:          &topicArn,
    MessageAttributes: messageAttributes,
}

result, err := client.Publish(input)
```

can someone please help me where I'm wrong in the above code ?

I have enabled debug logging and picked the logs from SDK and I can see that the request is also formed properly

> Action=Publish&Message=example&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name=Custom&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType=String.Array&MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue=%5B%22foo%40foo.com%22%2C%22%2B12345678909%22%5D&Subject=test-subject&TopicArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-west-2%3A0000000000%3Atest-topic&Version=2010-03-31

```
-----------------------------------------------------
2023/08/29 18:59:04 DEBUG: Response sns/Publish Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 294
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2023 13:29:03 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx
```